# How to get a path of inherited class using base class function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

This is the main.cpp

```
 Directory* c = dynamic_cast<Directory*>(r->getChild("c"));
        cout << c->addChild(true, "ca") << endl;
        cout << c->addChild(true, "cn") << endl;
        cout << c->addChild(false, "cf1") << endl;
        cout << c->list() << endl;

        cout << "================= Test 6 =================" << endl;
        cout << c->getPath() << endl;
        cout << c->getChild("cn")->getPath() << endl;
        cout << c->getChild("cf1")->getPath() << endl;
```

This is my expected output:

```
================= Test 6 =================
\c
\c\cn
\c\cf1
```

This is my base class - FSObject

```
class FSObject
{
private:
    string name;
    FSObject* parent; 
}
```

This is my inherited class - Directory

```
class Directory : public FSObject
{
public:
    Directory(string name, FSObject* parent) : FSObject(name, parent) {};
}
```

This is my inherited class - SADirectory

```
class SADirectory : public Directory
{
public:
    SADirectory(string name, FSObject* parent);
private:
    FSObject* children[DIR_SIZE]; 

    int count;
}
```

This is my another inherited class - File

```
  class File : public FSObject
    {
    private:
        string content; //the string content
    }
```

Considering the main.cpp, the addChild function can be used to add both file and sadirectory.
But, the question is, how can i get the result like the expected output to implement the getPath() in Class FSObject?
Thank you for your help.

This is my attempt for recursion of the gatPath()

```
 string FSObject::getPath(){ 
    if(this->getPath()=="\\"){ 
    return "";
     } 
    string temp = "\\";
     temp += this->parent->getPath() + this->name;
     return temp;
     }
```

Comment: Recurrent relation is `c.getPath()`-> `c.parent.getPath()`+`c.name`. You need to stop the recursion but we have no information about the way FS root is coded.

Comment: Show your attempt at `getPath`. Why do you expect child classes to complicate things?

Comment: string FSObject::getPath(){
 if(this->getPath()=="\\"){
  return "";
 }
 string temp = "\\";
  temp += this->parent->getPath() + this->name;
 return temp;
}
this is my attempt for recursion but doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and update it with any relevant information. Comments are not for posting updates to your question.

Comment: sorry about that i am new in this forum. I have edited my question now. Thank you for help.

Comment: Now this is rather... inconsistent. In order to compute `getPath()`, you go and compute `getPath()` first. Worse yet, you want `getPath()` to return `""` iff it returns `"\\"`.

Comment: i try to cout the value of c->parent but all the parent object return NULL. i don't know why it cannot return the value of c->parent like the expected output.

Comment: I don't see where you try this. I also don't see where you initialise `parent`. Please post a [mcve], thanks.